# Método nao salva arquivo de fotos

Tags: java, android

Estou fazendo uma aplicação em Android, só que nao consigo salva um arquivo de foto.

```
btnFoto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // Intent de camera
                Intent itCamera = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                //Caminho da foto
                caminhoFoto = getExternalFilesDir(null) + "/foto"+System.currentTimeMillis()+".jpg";
                Log.i("foto", caminhoFoto);
                // Criando objeto do tipo File
                File arquivoFoto = new File(caminhoFoto);
                // Paddando o Arquivo da foto por put Extra
                itCamera.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(arquivoFoto));
                //
                startActivityForResult(itCamera, CODIGO_CAMERA);
            }
        });
```

obs: estou usando para teste um Samsung com Android 6.0.1.

Comment: Oi, você gostaria de salvar a foto onde?

Comment: É apresentado algum erro?

Comment: Já verificou sobre as questões de permissão?